# CV question: How do I remove the horizontal line below my name if I'm using \documentclass{moderncv} and \moderncvtheme{casual}?

Tags: moderncv

I used LaTeX to write my CV. At this moment I need to remove the horizontal line that appears below my name (this line only appears at the top of the first page of the CV). How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule you mention is produced by `\makecvtitle` using

```
\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}
```

the quickest solution is to patch `\makecvtitle` to supress the rule:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{casual}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
  {}
  {}
  {}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user135328 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

With the latest moderncv, patch `\makecvhead`:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}                                                          
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}                                   
  {}                                                                            
  {}                                                                            
  {}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Indeed this works in `moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0]` in contrast to the answer of Gonzalo Medina.  Adding exact version information and a full minimal working document with its output would improve your answer.  Pointing to the file `moderncvheadii.sty` that contains the relevant command would be even more helpful.